# Differential Equations in Python

Tags: python, differential-equations

I'm working with a DE system, and I wanted to know which is the most commonly used python library to solve Differential Equations if any.

My Equations are non Linear First Order equations.

Comment: Have you tried ODEINT in Scipy.integrate? https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/SolveDifferentialEquations

Answer (score 10):

If you need to solve large nonlinear systems (especially stiff ones), the scipy tools will be slow and awkward. The [PyDSTool](http://pydstool.sourceforge.net/) package is now quite commonly used in this situation. It lets your equations be automatically converted into C code and integrates them with good solvers. It's especially good if you want to define state-defined events such as threshold crossings, add external input signals from arrays, or have other analyses done (such as bifurcation analysis, as the package includes an interface to AUTO).

Answer (score 8):

You use SciPy's `integrate`, which interfaces with the standard LAPACK routines for something like this.

See [this tutorial](http://www.tau.ac.il/~kineret/amit/scipy_tutorial/#x1-210004.4), which is just one I found on Google. [Here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) are the docs.

Answer (score 5):

For calculations in symbols - use **sympy**.

Answer (score 5):

You learn how to do Differential Equations in Python using the numpy and scipy packages on this website:

https://www.udacity.com/course/differential-equations-in-action--cs222

The course is Differential Equations in Action.

Answer (score 2):

Probably something in SciPy or NumPy.

See: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PyDSTool](http://www.ni.gsu.edu/~rclewley/PyDSTool/FrontPage.html) which is for Dynamical systems modeling, simulation and analysis environment. It is mostly use scipy and numpy