# Defining in a funky differential equation in python. (Not Trying to solve)

Tags: python, differential-equations, natural-logarithm

Sorry, I'm not entirely sure how to define this differential equation in python.

[image]

I understand there is a equation inside the equation, but how would you define this differential equation of natural log?

The above equation stems off of the actual Halo Mass Function

[image]

Edit: I'm trying plot this equation of given information of M's in the form of a structured array, not solve it. This is a equation inside of another equation that's called the Halo Mass function. It plots masses basically. So in this case, i'm trying to plot it. Hence, me asking how to define it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differential Equations in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847201/differential-equations-in-python)

Comment: In that case, i do not have initial conditions. This is a function inside the Halo Mass function. The point of this equation will play is graphing masses of Halo masses. I guess I should edit my question to be more elaborate.

Comment: Could you state what supposed to be an abscissa, and what supposed to be an ordinate, and what would be fixed parameters (plot Y vs X for a given A, B, C, ...)

Comment: @Severin Pappadeux Yes, sorry about that. The Abscissa (M) and ordinate  , the left part of the function, is based off of the original equation. But not to sound frank, i'm just curious on how you define the equation d(ln\sigma)/d(lnM) in defintion.

Comment: @DarthLazar well, d\log(M)/dM = 1/M, thus d\log(M) = dM/M. But why you want to deal with d(ln\sigma)/d(lnM)? `\log()` is monotonical function, so you could just use \log(M) as abscissa, it doesn't matter. So basically you have new `x=\log(M)`, equation in the form df/dx = `some integral`, and you want to plot it? Just compute integral, that's it, for each `x`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928750/numerical-ode-solving-in-python?rq=1

Comment: @hdost no, he is not trying to solve it, my guess of the moment is this is implicitly defined function which should be plotted